# a public action method was not found on controller, while it really is there

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, webdeploy

My application is experiencing this really weird issue. In one of my controllers I have an action with both `HttpGET` and `HttpPOST` annotations. The difference between them is that the `HttpPOST` action receives a model parameter. Other parameters are strings and nullable booleans. randomly out of nowhere as I dig through the Error Logs of my application I am finding The following exception, `a public action method was not found on controller`. If you make a GET request on that URL the view is returned even if you do not pass any parameters, the same things goes for the POST. I cant really think of what can be going on. The problem is on just this action. Can it be caused by publishing ? I mean I use web deploy to publish the website major changes are made twice in a week and minor changes are made twice in a day. But I'm getting this exception 10 times in a day maybe even more. and application health is really suffering from this. I get major CPU usage jumps. What can I do to troubleshoot this ?

Comment: are you saying that the same controller method (action) is marked with `GET` and `POST` ?  I've never seen that done before.  If your app's health is suffering, I would consider making them separate controller methods (different actions in MVC speak)

Comment: Those are two separate methods of course. Same controller and different methods. One is marked with GET and the other is POST.

Answer (score 1):

You say the get has nullable booleans. do you pass empty values to those in your get requests? otherwise it will not work.

for example

```
public ActionResult GetMyData(string name, bool? isItTrue){
    return View()
}
```

your request has to be like this even `isItTrue` is `null`

```
http://localhost/controller/getmydata?name=me&isItTrue=
```

Comment: Let me double check that case.